# Error al llamar método conectarBD desde una clase en un frame de java Swing

Tags: java, java-swing

tardes o noche comunidad espero que se encuentren bien en periodos de cuarentena, vengo hacia ustedes con un problema al cuál no le veo una solución por lo que me gustaría saber de otras opiniones si no es mucha molestia.

**JFrame**

```
package gui;

import internalFrames.iFrameAnadirPedido;
import internalFrames.iFrameArrendarLibros;
import internalFrames.iFrameArriendo;
import internalFrames.iFrameVenderLibros;
import internalFrames.iFrameVentas;
import internalFrames.iFrameVerCliente;
import internalFrames.iFrameVerDistribuidor;
import internalFrames.iFrameVerLibros;
import internalFrames.iFrameVerMultas;
import internalFrames.iFrameVerTrabajador;
import internalFrames.iFrameVerTrabajador;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import model.utils.ConexionBD;

public class Inicio extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    iFrameVerLibros verLibros = new iFrameVerLibros();
    iFrameArrendarLibros arrendarLibros = new iFrameArrendarLibros();
    iFrameVenderLibros venderLibros = new iFrameVenderLibros();
    iFrameVentas verVentas = new iFrameVentas();
    iFrameArriendo verArriendo = new iFrameArriendo();
    iFrameVerMultas verMultas = new iFrameVerMultas();
    iFrameVerDistribuidor verDistribuidores = new iFrameVerDistribuidor();
    iFrameAnadirPedido anadirPedido = new iFrameAnadirPedido();
    iFrameVerCliente verCliente = new iFrameVerCliente();
    iFrameVerTrabajador verTrabajador = new iFrameVerTrabajador();

    public ConexionBD con;

    public Inicio() {

        initComponents();
        con.conectarBD();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.add(verLibros);
        this.add(venderLibros);
        this.add(arrendarLibros);
        this.add(verVentas);
        this.add(verArriendo);
        this.add(verMultas);
        this.add(verDistribuidores);
        this.add(anadirPedido);
        this.add(verCliente);
        this.add(verTrabajador);

    }
```

Por el momento en este frame no tengo más que los actions que llevan a los respectivos IFrames

**Clase conexionBD**

```
 package model.utils;

    import static java.net.Authenticator.RequestorType.SERVER;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.plaf.RootPaneUI;
    import static sun.net.ftp.FtpDirEntry.Permission.USER;

    public class ConexionBD {

         private final String SERVER = "localhost";

        private final String PASSWORD = "";
        private final String USER = "root";

        protected Connection conexion;


        public Connection getConexion() {
            return conexion;
        }

        public void setConexion(Connection conexion) {
            this.conexion = conexion;
        }

        public boolean conectarBD() {
           try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                String cadena = "jdbc:mysql://" + SERVER + ":3306/biblioteca";
                this.conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(cadena, USER, PASSWORD);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ConexionBD c = new ConexionBD();
            System.out.println(c.conectarBD());
        }
    }
```

Em esta clase tengo un método que se conecta a una base de datos, el tema está es que no quiero presionar un botón para conectarme a la bd si no que al momento de darle run se ejecute, mi problema esta en que al llamar el método después de initComponents() tira un excepción y no sé a que se debe. Espero no incomodar a nadie con mi solicitud, desde ya muhcas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Fíjate en lo que haces en esa función `main` que no se por qué tienes en la clase de la conexión. Hace un `new` para crear el objeto. Pues eso mismo tendrías que hacer tú en la función `Inicio` antes de usar el objeto `con`. Si no haces esto, la variable `con` estará a null y por eso te da la excepción `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Cuales son las lineas 45 y 285 de tu clase Inicio? , recuerda revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: @SuperG280 Efectivamente el problema era que no estaba llamado al constructor, así que haciendo eso logré solucionar el problema, lo de main es más que nada para ver si conectaba con la base de datos. Muchas gracias